# How to extract URL actually opened page from browser i.e. Google Chrome using Linux bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, url, browser, extract

I need some help.

I wanna write bash script in Linux that need URL actually opened page in browser.

I try found some answer on Stack, but I failed.

How can I do this?

1. Is there some file with history of opened URL that I can extract from it?
2. Or there is some more complicated way? Maybe you know some way of get URL to file? And I can get it then from this file?
3. Maybe you know some other ways of do that...

I don't know how do this...

Any help would be appreciated.:)

Comment: [Similar cross-site question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241658/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-url-from-current-tab-in-google-chrome), it addresses both chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the url to the window title with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-in-title/ignpacbgnbnkaiooknalneoeladjnfgb , then you can see it with `wmctrl -l`

Comment: Yes, but you can find this add-on by google search and it  works :) I try use it today and I'll write here if that all works. Thanks for this tip !